# ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg.packages

Tags: python, ros

I am trying to run:-
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

but I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 55, in <module>
    import xacro
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from roslaunch import substitution_args
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .launch import ROSLaunchRunner
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 55, in <module>
    from roslaunch.nodeprocess import create_master_process, create_node_process
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/nodeprocess.py", line 49, in <module>
    from roslaunch.node_args import create_local_process_args
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/node_args.py", line 53, in <module>
    import roslib.packages
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    import roslib.stacks
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/stacks.py", line 46, in <module>
    import roslib.packages
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 49, in <module>
    from catkin.find_in_workspaces import find_in_workspaces as catkin_find
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py", line 36, in <module>


from catkin_pkg.packages import find_packages
ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg.packages
while processing /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xacro/xacro.py '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1].
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This worked for me

```
pip install catkin_pkg
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who have conda installed, here is the solution:
https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/issues/118#issuecomment-1355078266

You need to install `catkin_pkg` into the environment. I'm using conda and I had to install `catkin_pkg`, `empy`, and `lark`:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge catkin_pkg empy lark
```

Answer (score 0):

On Arch Linux: In my case, I installed from an AUR package `python2-catkin_pkg` which installed the library at `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. So just do a symlink from `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg`. So do this when you're in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg catkin_pkg
```

Comment: You have to link __from__ system-python packages to ros packages: `ln -s /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/catkin_pkg /opt/ros/melodic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/catkin_pkg`

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your python version is too high as it was in my case. Try to use the system default python first.

Go back to `/usr/bin/python3` and use that as the default.