# ROS2 catkin_pkg not found (is installed and using version 3.8)

Tags: python, cmake, ros2

I built a new package using moveit2 for panda and when I try to colcon build I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 22, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:95 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python3.8
  /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py
  /home/mikel/dualpandaWS/src/franka_moveit_config/package.xml
  /home/mikel/dualpandaWS/build/franka_moveit_config/ament_cmake_core/package.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:49 (_ament_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package.cmake:63 (ament_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (ament_package)
```

I have searched through interent and tried `sudo apt install python3-catkin-pkg` and `sudo update-alternatives --config python` to see what python version I'm using, which returns:

```
There is only one alternative in link group python (providing /usr/bin/python): /usr/bin/python3.8
Nothing to configure
```

I dont know what can I do to solve this problem, seems that I lack some kind of configuration so I can build my workspace... Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you [installed colcon](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html#install-colcon):

```
sudo apt install python3-colcon-common-extensions
```

also [rosdep](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#install-dependencies-using-rosdep) might help you to install dependencies:

```
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths src -y --ignore-src
```

and also make sure you source your ros2 env (you seem to done so already but just incase).

other than that your question seems similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992442/importerror-no-module-named-catkin-pkg-packages) in that case

```
pip install catkin_pkg
```